Disable WooCommerce Checkout Place Order Button based on the User ID
With the code below, I am trying to disable the order button for non-allowed users based on their ID, in WooCommerce checkout:
add_filter( 'woocommerce_order_button_html', 'replace_order_button_html', 10, 2 );
function replace_order_button_html( $order_button ) {
    if ( is_admin() && ! defined( 'DOING_AJAX' ) )
        return;

    $wpuser_object = wp_get_current_user_id();
    $allowed_users = array( 1, 2);

    if ( array_intersect($allowed_users, $wpuser_object->id) ){
    
        $order_button_text = __( "Place Order", "woocommerce" );

        $style = ' style="color:#fff;cursor:not-allowed;background-color:#999;"';
        return '<a class="button alt"'.$style.' name="woocommerce_checkout_place_order" id="place_order" >' . esc_html( $order_button_text ) . '</a>';
    }
}

But it doesn't work at all.
What I am doing wrong?

Doesn't your code hide the button entirely? What's stopping you from adding a disabled attribute instead?

There are some mistakes and unnecessary things in your code:

You need to use in_array() instead of array_intersect(),
To get the current user ID, use get_current_user_id(),
You can add "disabled" selector class instead of custom CSS styling,
You need to replace the type attribute value from "submit" to "button", to avoid the order to be placed ("disabled" attribute will not work here),
always return the main variable argument at the end when using filter hooks.

Try the following simplified and revised code:
add_filter( 'woocommerce_order_button_html', 'disable_conditionally_order_button_html', 10 );
function disable_conditionally_order_button_html( $button_html ) {
    $allowed_users_ids = array( 1, 2 );

    if ( ! in_array( get_current_user_id(), $allowed_users_ids ) ) {
        return str_replace(['type="submit"', 'class="button alt'], ['type="button"', 'class="button alt disabled'], $button_html );
    }
    return $button_html;
}

Code goes in functions.php file of your child theme (or in a plugin). Tested and works.


I actually wanted to specify user ids to disable in the array. I'm assuming I just remove the ! from in_array?

As you named the related variable  $allowed_users in your code, for me, it was logical that the specified array of user IDs were Allowed users… So yes, just remove the ! in the IF statement.

All sorted. Merci!
